# Connect To Host With PureFTP

Tags: lubuntu, pure-ftpd

I have pureftp up and running on my home machine.  I am attempting to connect to it from outside of my network, using filezilla.  Everything seems to go swell, but filezilla is not able to connect.  This is the only log that filezilla shows, what is stopping the connection from being succesful?

```
2016-05-04 09:10:23 17108 1 Status: Resolving address of XXX.XXX.XXXX.org
2016-05-04 09:10:23 17108 1 Status: Connecting to XX.XX.XXX.XXX:81...
2016-05-04 09:10:23 17108 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2016-05-04 09:10:43 17108 1 Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
2016-05-04 09:10:43 17108 1 Error: Could not connect to server
```

I am connecting to a hostname that I have forwarded to my WAN IP and port 81 directed to my LAN IP.

**EDIT**
If I open terminal on the server computer and type `ftp XXX.XXX.XXXX.org` the output terminal gives is

```
Request timed out
```

SO it seems I can not even connect on my local machine.  Did I miss a step when setting up the ftp?

**EDIT 2**
If I run the command `ftp 127.0.0.1` the output is

```
owner@OwnerBackup:~$ ftp 127.0.0.1<br>
Connected to 127.0.0.1.<br>
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------<br>
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.<br>
220-Local time is now 10:37. Server port: 21.<br>
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login<br>
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.<br>
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.<br>
Name (127.0.0.1:owner): <br>
```

**EDIT 3**
IP Tables shows below:

```
owner@OwnerBackup:~$ sudo iptables -L<br>
[sudo] password for owner: <br>
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)<br>
target     prot opt source               destination   <br>      
<br>
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)<br>
target     prot opt source               destination   <br>      
<br>
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)<br>
target     prot opt source               destination   <br>
```

As far as port forwarding, which ports would I need to forward for this?  Meaning, I have a FTP server up and running on 2 other LAN IP's...
Ports 20 - 21 forward to LAN IP ending in .300
Ports 990 - 999 forward to LAN IP ending in .350
Ports 2000 - 2100 forwarded to LAN IP ending in .360 (this machine)

**EDIT # 4** 
Following the suggestions listed in my one answer, I had not altered the default listening port for my server to listen on.   Changing such, now when I try to connect this is the error log that I get.  What do I need to do in order to successfully connect?

```
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Status: Resolving address of XXX.XXX.XXXX.org
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Status: Connecting to 9XX.XX.XXX.XXX:2050...
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 220-You are user number 2 of 50 allowed.
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 220-Local time is now 14:46. Server port: 2050.
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 500 This security scheme is not implemented
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Command: AUTH SSL
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 500 This security scheme is not implemented
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Command: USER baduser
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Response: 331 User baduser OK. Password required
2016-05-04 14:46:49 15764 1 Command: PASS *******
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Response: 230 OK. Current directory is /
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Response: 200 OK, UTF-8 enabled
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Status: Logged in
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Command: PWD
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Response: 257 "/" is your current location
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Command: TYPE I
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Command: PASV
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XXX,X,XX,XX,XXX)
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
2016-05-04 14:46:51 15764 1 Command: MLSD
2016-05-04 14:47:03 15764 1 Error: Directory listing aborted by usercd
```

Comment: Both those requests are going to the external address, because your ftp includes the external domain name.  What does `ftp 127.0.0.1` give you when run on the machine you have the FTP service running on (please add the output to your question, not as a comment).

Comment: @EightBitTony - edit includes requested info

Comment: So you either have a firewall in the way on your local machine (`sudo iptables -L`) or you haven't set the port forwarding up properly on your router.  Note that FTP requires more than just port 21.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to double check:

1) You can connect locally

2) You can ftp 127.0.0.1 from terminal

3) You set-up port forwarding in your router for the Port Range

4) You changed the default listening port of your ftp server to mirror one of the ports in the range set-up in your router.

In my experience when I am having FTP issues it stems from one of the above, usually the 4th one!

Comment: See my edit -- how would I remedy this?